# Can't do the money time travel on 3DS Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

So on my 3DS, brand new, I haven't changed the time on there. The options for the 3DS itself. However, I've messed with the Animal Crossing time more then once, usually only skipping 3 or 4 days. I can't do the money time travel thing, however. I've tried so many times. What do I do?

Comment: Please provide more details on what you are trying so that we can identify what you are doing wrong. I googled "animal crossing new leaf 3ds money time travel" and the first result was http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUQqBieSOhU which explains the process quite simply. Is there something specific about the process that is confusing you?

Comment: What exactly is Money Time Traveling? I know how to do normal time traveling. Also, please be more descriptive about what is preventing you. Does it not let you edit the time in-game?

Comment: @ShadowZorgon Money time travel is just saving like 2 million or more bells in the bank and then skipping an entire year at a time repeatedly to get large interest payments.

Comment: Ah, i have not yet earned the investment thing (Automatic Bell Deposit?).

Comment: No you just go to the ATM in the post office?

Comment: i have tried Time Travel for about 30 years , but nothing changed with my Account, is it not works in acnl ? because I use that trick on AC WW

Answer (score 1):

To use this cheat/hack, you need to change your 3DS time (in system settings) not the AC:NF time that Isabelle asks if you want to change. It is best to travel as far as you can into the future (the year 2050 I think). Then you will get a letter from the post office saying that you have gained a certain number of bells and they can be taken out at the post office bell point. Something to remember though, you will get lots and lots of weeds throughout your town if you do this multiple times.

NOTE:
You only get interest after a month, so a couple of days difference will do nothing.